# Is there a facebook webhook for when user removes the app from business integrations?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I would like to handle the case when a user removes my app manually from business integrations.

I want to know 2 things:

1- What webhook should I use?

2- Does this webhook return the account id of the user?

I have investigated **ad_account** webhook in **Application** object but I'm not sure from the documentation if that is the webhook I need. I also don't know what the fields in the payload represent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

**Method 1:**
*You can enable a deauthorize callback through the App Dashboard. Just go to your app, then choose the Products, then Facebook Login, and finally Settings.*
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#deauth-callback

**Method 2:**
By configuring a Permissions Webhook to your app:

1. Add the "Webhooks" product to your app
2. Select "Permissions" from the list
3. Configure the Callback URL, Verify Token & enable the "Include values" switch
4. Subscribe to the "connected" field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/permissions/#connected

You will now receive the following object when a user installs/removes your app:

```
"object": "permissions", "entry": [{"id": "10000123456789", "uid": "10000123456789", "time": 1576834276, "changes": [{"verb": "revoked", "field": "connected"}]}]}
```

Where "uid" is the account id of the user (app scoped user ID).

Additionally, you can also subscribe to individual permissions a user accepts/removes in your app, such as email address:

```
{"object": "permissions", "entry": [{"id": "10000123456789", "uid": "10000123456789", "time": 1576836231, "changes": [{"value": {"verb": "revoked"}, "field": "email"}]}]}
```